# Node gear won't restart on OpenShift, how can I check the logs?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a `OpenShift` Node application that stopped running last night (for no reason it appears).

Restarting will not work from the online console or the command line tool resulting in an error page saying:

```
"We appear to be having technical difficulties
Unhandled exception reference #848361ee8043499b3a5498d2ce3bb0d1: too many connection resets `(due to Timeout::Error - Timeout::Error) after 1 requests on 43142700, last used 240.104443054 seconds ago"`
```

Is there a way to log in to the application to see what's going wrong when trying to start the node application?

I don't seem to be able to ssh into the application to get to my log files.

Or is the problem with `OpenShift` and not my application?

Answer (score 0):

At OpenShift management console, choose your application, and click the link at your right labeled "Want to log in to your application?". You can open an ssh session with that.

Comment: unfortunately that wont work. I guess you can only login to a running application

Comment: Ooops, I misread the issue, sorry (ssh is useful if the app, not the gear, is the one that won't boot). [Status page](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status) doesn't show any problem either :(

Answer (score 0):

You can check the application logs using `rhc tail --app <app_name>` command. It looks to me that it is giving database connection error. To SSH into your application, use `rhc ssh --app <app_name>` command. I would recommend if `rhc app-restart` is not working then try to use `rhc force-stop-app` command and the `rhc start --app` command.

Comment: that does not return anything either. I do have a mysql cartridge running that seems to be working fine.

Comment: Sorry I read your edit too late. When force-stopping the app I got a "Server returned an unexpected error code: 504". The status of my node cartridge is still "unknown" but now my mysql cartridge status has changed to "stopped". Starting the app with rhc start will restart the mysql cartridge but not the node cartridge (remains status "unknown")

Comment: What does rhc tail command show when you start the application?

Comment: rhc tail does not return anything (I guess because the cartrige is not running)

Comment: Then ssh into your application gear and then go to logs directory cd $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR. In this directory you will find the logs of your application.

Comment: I am not able to ssh into the gear. I did "rhc app show <appname> --gears" to display the gears and receiving the SSH URL. But when running "ssh <sshurl>" nothing gets returned

Comment: The app is now running again (after >12h downtime) for no obvious reason. I contacted RedHat for explanation.